# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressHelper' not found

Tags: macos, behat

Yesterday I've installed phpunit with pear, and finally created a symbolic link from /usr/local/bin/behat to /usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.16/bin/phpunit.

Now I am trying to do the same thing with Behat. What I've done is:

```
sudo pear upgrade PEAR
sudo pear channel-discover pear.behat.org
sudo pear install --alldeps behat/behat
```

Now, when I run

```
$ /usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.16/bin/behat
```

I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressHelper' not found in /usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.16/lib/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php on line 973
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.16/bin/behat:0
PHP   2. Behat\Behat\Console\BehatApplication->__construct() /usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.16/bin/behat:26
PHP   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->__construct() /usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.16/lib/php/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Console/BehatApplication.php:32
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getDefaultHelperSet() /usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.16/lib/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:83

Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressHelper' not found in /usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.16/lib/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php on line 973

Call Stack:
    0.0003     233344   1. {main}() /usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.16/bin/behat:0
    0.0068     641984   2. Behat\Behat\Console\BehatApplication->__construct() /usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.16/bin/behat:26
    0.0068     642072   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->__construct() /usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.16/lib/php/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Console/BehatApplication.php:32
    0.0068     642512   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getDefaultHelperSet() /usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.16/lib/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:83
```

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good site to post it, but..to help you, i found this explication in Github official repository: https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/293

Seems helpfully. (okay, it not help, but...it's a good explication for this bug)

Good luck.